# How do I find Notion Users Ids?

Tags: notion-api

To be able to assign a person property to a person through the api you need their Notion Id. How do I go about getting that info? I did a Google search and only 1 link appeared and I'm having issues navigating the steps. It has you using the Notion Developer Tools software which I can't find.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the list all users API.

So for python it'll look like this.

```
import os

from notion_client import Client

notion = Client(auth=os.environ["NOTION_API_KEY"])

print(notion.users.list())
```

And then you can just copy and paste the ids and then assign them as properties.

```
{
  "people": [{
    "id": "e89bbf47-2883-4a58-b2c5-f13fe09dd130"
  }]
}
```